# Unable to login through android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an application in which i am loading a URL in android Webview. There is a login page in this URL. I am unable to login through android webview using the valid username/password but i can login using android browser.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: did your webview allow javascript execution? and what do you mean by unable to login? what is your expectation after you click "login" button in the webview?

Comment: WebSettings wsettings = webView.getSettings();wsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  Yes,  i had enabled javascript for webview. The URL is navigating to menu screen after successful login in android browser but not in android webview

Comment: I see, after login clicked does it give you any error message instead then?

Comment: no i dont see any error msg. Do i need to enable any extras websettings to webview?

Comment: do you have something like this: webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); ?